# Automatically extract images from Chrome cache on OSX

Tags: macos, google-chrome

I want to recover all the images from a particular domain that I previously visited in Chrome. I've looked in ~/Library/Caches/Google/Chrome/Default/Cache and there a bunch of gzipped files, but I tried extracting one of them and found that it only contained a bunch of minified JS.

I've seen [CacheCopy](http://cachecopy.codeplex.com/) and [ChromeCacheView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) but those are only for Windows. Is there an easy way to do this on OSX?